# How can I proceed only if the window I just opened is closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have two WPF windows.
Window1's button calling Window2, Window2 updates something, and then I want to proceed exactly where I stopped in Window1.

This is the code in Window1 inside a button_Click:

```
Window2 window = new Window2();
window.Show();
* wait until Window2 closes
//continue with other actions
```

How do I wait?

I saw this: [wpf c# button wait for a button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888608/wpf-c-sharp-button-wait-for-a-button-press)
But how can I pass it from a different (already closed) window?

Comment: why dont you use Window.ShowDialog()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Window.ShowDialog` method, it opens a window and and waits for window closing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

```
Nullable<bool> dialogResult = window.ShowDialog();
// Test dialogResult: it is true if dialog was closed by OK button
```

Windows used as modal dialogs are usually contain OK and Cancel buttons, and programmed by such way, that pressing OK returns `true` from `ShowDialog` methid.

See also: Creating a Modal Custom Dialog Box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window.ShowDialog()` instead of Show(). This will open a modal window and will wait till it closes